# symfony 2 /doctrine 2 : how to identify what parts of the code result in query leaks

Tags: php, symfony, memory-leaks, doctrine-orm, doctrine

So I am using symfony 2 and doctrine 2.

I am often fetching objects with a custom querybuilder, at least to avoid query leaks when looping through my objects and calling their nested elements.

However, I find it's sometimes difficult to figure out which part of the code is triggering a new request, ie where you forgot to fetch data before using it.

From the symfony2 profiler -> doctrine, I know what are the extra request, but is there a way to get back to the trace generating those requests ?? that would be very helpful !

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there any way you could post some code?

Comment: well, I'm not looking for something generic, a way to explore the code and identify what triggers an database query. I don't have relevant code here,
say I am calling $this->getDoctrine->getRepository('User')->findAll() : how can I find this line back when looking at the doctrine tab in the profiler ?